# InDesign Layers

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, layers

Is there any possibility to add words from the same text column to the different layers? The thing is that some words from the text must be specifically moved to 'No translate' layer as the whole document will be sent to translator. Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can only move whole text boxes to a different layer. A little labour intensive but perhaps you could do either of these:

- Use a character style to make all of the words you don't want to be translated red / bold / something obviously different. Post translation, just remove the character style.
- You could also be more extreme and change the font of the words you do not want to be changed (the tell the translator). Once the doc has been translated, use Type > Find Font to go through and change them all back in one go.